# Compile error: boost::promise<T>::set_value(const T&) doesn't exist

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors

I'm having problems with Boost.Thread's futures: I can't seem to put anything but a primitive type into a promise, future, or packaged task.

Here is a minimal testcase:

```
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>

struct foo
{
    foo(int i_): i(i_) {}
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    // A const future isn't much use, but I needed to prove
    // the problem wasn't me trying to copy a unique_future
    const boost::unique_future<foo>& fut = boost::make_ready_future( foo(42) );
}
```

With `BOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE` defined before including the Boost.Future header I get the following error with gcc 4.8.2 and Boost 1.55 (full output [here](http://pastebin.com/0sePWBWr)):

```
../../deps/boost/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:3634:5: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::promise<foo>::set_value(const foo&)’
     p.set_value(boost::forward<future_value_type>(value));
     ^
```

There seems to be no overload of promise::set_value() that takes a const lvalue reference. Looking at `promise` and `future_traits` in `future.hpp` it seems that the const lvalue ref overload will only exist when `BOOST_NO_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES` is undefined. That makes no sense to me however...surely the const lvalue ref overload is needed precisely when there are no rvalue references? (Note this happens even if I pass a mutable lvalue ref to `make_ready_future()`).

If I don't define `BOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE` it fails compilation with the following error (full output [here](http://pastebin.com/jBwiJLeC)):

```
../../deps/boost/include/boost/thread/detail/move.hpp:183:54: error: no matching function for call to boost::unique_future<foo>::unique_future(boost::unique_future<foo>)’
#define BOOST_THREAD_MAKE_RV_REF(RVALUE) RVALUE.move()
                                                     ^
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: Keep #define BOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE. And compile it as: g++ boosttest.cpp -I boost_1_55/include -std=c++11 -L ./boost_1_55/lib/ -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lpthread

Comment: huh, just realized that BOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE doesn't matter if we use -std=c++11

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately I can't use C++11 :-(

Comment: _surely the const lvalue ref overload is needed precisely when there are no rvalue references?_ It's always needed, it's part of the standardized API for `std::promise`, and you don't only want to be able to make a promise ready with rvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems from the boost-users mailing list that this is a bug in Boost and is also present in 1.56 - looks like it's fundamentally broken in C++03 mode.

Bug report: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10340